Post API alert rule not appeared in grafana UI
naaaa
4d
Hello Team,
Good Day.
Need your help!
With postman tried GET and POST API calls for grafana. When we ran GET call from DEV cluster the response code is 200 and for PUT/POST call to UAT cluster is successful with response code 201. But when we logged in to UI of UAT box and searched for Alert in Alert rule. But did not find the alert in UI.
Which means API call is successful but alert not appearing in grafana UI.
We have tried below:
In json payload :
Id, folderid, update timestamp made to null. The response code is 400.
Org made to 1 and tried…but response code is 400.
Tried with header x-provision to string/true…response code 400.
Could you please help to resolve issue.

Tried with postman by making orgid to 1
By changing folderid and data source

I'd
By removing update timestamp from het api resuot

Hello, Issue resolved by passing folderUI in json. We have tried to create folder with folder API, but it's by default creating folder in dashboard.  We need help to create folder in Alert-rule through API. Can some one help here
